# %run command to run .ipynb file forces .py extension

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am trying to execute a simple run command:

```
%run /WaterfallViz.ipynb
```

But no matter how I format it I keep getting the same error:

```
ERROR:root:File `'/WaterfallViz.ipynb.py'` not found.
```

How do I prevent the .py extension to insert itself at the end of the file name?

Answer (score 1):

**If you have moved the notebook file** where you `%run` another notebook, unfortunately Jupyter will still reference to the original directory path.

To fix this behavior, simply:

- save your notebook
- create a new notebook
- copy the content from the original notebook
- open the new notebook file

The `%run` now should work as the "directory path" is the one you are expecting, and the `.ipynb` file will be picked up instead of trying to open a `.py` file too.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and I found out other ways to import the notebook that avoid this error, without needing to follow all the process recommended before (creating a new notebook, etc).

You need to first install a library:
pip install import-ipynb

Then, import it in your notebook:
import import_ipynb

And finally you can import your file:
import WaterfallViz